# Bash script to sendmail if a command line output doesn't contain a srting

Tags: bash, shell, centos, sh

I've installed Clamav on my webserver

I know that there are a lot of shell scripts to do daily scan

But unfortunately I can't understand its lines :)

And I want to create a simple bash script to scan the /home directory and send me an email if there are infected files

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(clamscan -i /home &> /dev/null)
if [[ $var != *Infected files: 0* ]]
then
  echo "Subject: There are infected files" | sendmail -v root
fi
```

But the previous code doesn't work good

note : the problem in the code not in the file permission

**UPDATE**

The final worked code

```
#!/bin/bash
scanoutput=$(clamscan -ri /home 2>&1)
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
echo -e "Subject: ClamScan: there are infected files\nTo: root\n\n$scanoutput" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
fi
```

Comment: "doesn't work probably"..... So, your cat is on fire and your pickup truck just gave birth to a hippopotamus? Stating *how* something isn't working is often quite useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `exit code` instead of using the string output.
In the clamscan manual there is the follow

```
RETURN CODES
       0 : No virus found.

       1 : Virus(es) found.

       2 : Some error(s) occured.
```

So you can try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
clamscan -i /home &> /dev/null
clamscan_exit_code="$?"

if [[ "${clamscan_exit_code}" == '1' ]]; then
  echo "Subject: There are infected files" | sendmail -v root
fi
```

Also you have the possibility to send a specific email in case where there is some error by checking `exit code == 2`.

Comment: Beat me to it +1. Nice idea.

Comment: but what about if I want to send the scanning output as a body of the message?

Comment: I suggest you to redirect the command output to a file like `clamscan -i /home &> scan_output.txt`, and then attach it to the email.

Comment: @JonathaDaguerre thanks for helping, I updated my question and added the final code 1 minute ago

Answer (score 2):

You have to quote or escape spaces in the string you want to compare to:

```
[[ $var != *"Infected files: 0"* ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This [[ answer ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41249259/1620779) suggests another approach to solving your problem, but I slightly modify it to the below form

```
#!/bin/bash
clamscan --quiet /home 2>/dev/null || echo "System infected" | sendmail -v root
```

PS: Fixed wrong logical expression

Comment: thanks a lot, but I'm going to send the output in the message body